# Installing iText 7 without maven

Tags: installation, itext, itext7

We are upgrading from iText 2.1.7 to the iText 7.1.13 latest version. we are not using maven. Its a existing project so we cant change it to maven. Just directly adding the jar. For the iText 2.1.7 we have iText-2.1.7 jar, but now I can't seem to find the main iText-7.1.13 jar. where can I get iText jar.
The zip files here provide the supporting jar but does not contain - iText jar. https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases/tag/7.1.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iText 7 there is not one single jar, it is split up in several modules. You need *all* the jars in the `...-only-jars.zip` on the page your provided. Ok, maybe not *all* the jars, if you don't use certain features, but at least `io`, `kernel`, `layout` and maybe other modules too, depending on which features you need. For example if you don't use barcodes then you don't need the `barcodes` jar.

Also, iText 7 is a complete rewrite, and the API is not backwards compatible. Which means that you may need to rewrite parts of your code.

Comment: Thank you Amedee. It worked as you said. I had to load io, kernal, layout.